# Azure: ChangeDatabase does not work

Tags: c#, sql-server, azure-sql-database

I am trying to use my existing application which work with SQL Server to work with Azure database.
When I use this code to change the current db I receive the error

```
 if (connection.Database != db)
 {
    connection.ChangeDatabase(db); // <---
 }
 if (connection.State != ConnectionState.Open)
    connection.Open();
```

---

USE statement is not supported to switch between databases. 
Use a new connection to connect to a different database.

Is there any way to change db in existing connection?

Comment: Why don't you just use a new connection, as stated in the error?

Comment: I am trying: I get the connection.ConnectionString, then replace the db name, then set it to the new connection. But I use SQL auth. and the current connection does not contain the user password.

Comment: Instead of changing database context try using cross database queries as mentioned on the following article: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/querying-remote-databases-in-azure-sql-db/

Comment: @AlbertoMorillo isn't that only for an elastic database setup?

Comment: No, you are not trying to create a new connection. You're trying to change the connection string of an existing connection.

Comment: @Ksib You are correct. To use elastic queries you should consider moving to elastic pools.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks to all, yet another thing: to create the new connection using the existing connection.ConnectionString I fixed:

Persist Security Info=True